# Google Invisible Captcha "something went wrong" error upon form submission

Tags: magento-1.6, captcha, google, recaptcha, magento1.6.2

I have a similar issue to:
[Amasty Invisible Captch issue](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/227896/amasty-invisible-captch-issue)

I have a register form that has an error **"something went wrong"** upon submission when using Magento Google Invisible Captcha.
There are no errors thrown into the console to help debug this issue.

The form submits perfectly when the captcha plugin is disabled but I need it enabled to stop spam form submissions.

Versions:

> Magento ver. 1.6.2.0

Any help would be much appreciated.
Cheers

**EDIT**
I have enabled logs to try figure this out.
amasty_InvisibleCaptcha.log:

> "exception 'Zend_Http_Exception' with message 'Invalid HTTP response
>   version: 2'"

Comment: Did you register an API Key?

Comment: Yes i have, I have added log files to the question to help

Answer (score 0):

Just Go on this link:https://github.com/olegkoval/magento-contacts_form_captcha

Download this extension and install it.Installation and configuration files are also attach with it.